# Is it possible to add ExtensionData to a Dynamics WebApi call?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dataverse

I am creating a many-to-many relationship in DataVerse using this POST.

```
https://mysite.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/new_classes(649c332d-ca46-ee11-be6f-00224894adf7)/new_class_new_student/$ref

"body": {"@odata.context":"https://mysite.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#$ref",
        "@odata.id":"new_students(574af921-62f8-ec11-813d-005056893571)"}
```

And that works beautifully. However I have a Dynamics CE plugin on the Associate method, that I use to maintain a custom many-to-many with additional columns. I'd like to pass in some of that additional data in the call, let's say StartDate.

On the plugin side, when it runs, I get an EntityReferenceCollection for students with the id I passed in above (although I only passed in one student).

```
EntityReferenceCollection students = (EntityReferenceCollection)context.InputParameters["RelatedEntities"];
```

When debugging, I see the student in the collection has an ExtensionData property.

[image: ExtensionData property]

Is there a way to pass ExtensionData in the POST?

```
"body": {"@odata.context":"https://mysite.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#$ref",
        "@odata.id":"new_students(574af921-62f8-ec11-813d-005056893571)", 
        "ExtensionData":"{"StartDate":"12/12/2023"}"}
```